# Dictionary Comprehension for list values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I want to know if there's a more Pythonic way of doing the following, perhaps using dictionary comprehensions:

```
A = some list
D = {}
for i,v in enumerate(A):
    if v in D:
        D[v].append(i)
    else:
        D[v] = [i]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
D = defaultdict(list)
[D[v].append(i) for i, v in enumerate(A)]
```

Using `setdefault`:

```
D = {}
[D.setdefault(v, []).append(i) for i, v in enumerate(A)]
```

I can't figure any mean to use a dictionnary comprehension without sorting the data:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
{v: ids for v, ids in groupby(enumerate(sorted(A)), itemgetter(1))}
```

Performances:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from random import randint

A = tuple(randint(0, 100) for _ in range(1000))

def one():
    D = defaultdict(list)
    [D[v].append(i) for i, v in enumerate(A)]

def two():
    D = {}
    [D.setdefault(v, []).append(i) for i, v in enumerate(A)]

def three():
    {v: ids for v, ids in groupby(enumerate(sorted(A)), itemgetter(1))}


from timeit import timeit

for func in (one, two, three):
    print(func.__name__ + ':', timeit(func, number=1000))
```

Results (as always, the simplest win):

```
one: 0.25547646999984863
two: 0.3754340969971963
three: 0.5032370890003222
```

Comment: Is it really Pythonic to use list-comprehensions merely as a means of doing work? I'll admit, I've run into that issue before, and considered list-comps as a way to get it done, but it feels hacky. Other than that, though, I agree with `defaultdict` as the clearest answer.

Comment: The other way is using `map`, but list comprehension is [much more readable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/3077939), and generally [preferred](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~erdmann/mse350/topics/list_comprehensions.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i,v in enumerate(A):
    d[v].append(i)
```

You can see that the values of the resulting dictionary are `list`s, the elements of which are to be produced while traversing. If you insist on doing a dict comp, you have to first find all the `(value, [indices])`, then do a dict comp on `[(k,[v])]`, which just means extra acrobatics without any benefit.

Comment: Actually, arrived at this solution from looking at the selected answer.

Comment: @user2804747 Great. If you are dealing with data transformations using mainly dictionaries `collections` module is worth a read.